# MKMapView in loadView method

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, mkmapview

I have a silly question to ask and the question is that i have been working with MapKit Framework and found that whenever i am setting the frames and mapType of the object of MKMapView in the init method i get a blank view but when i set the frame and mapType in the loadView method i can view the map interface.

Why is this so? i am using sdk 3.1

Please help

here's my code

```
- (void)loadView {
    [super loadView];
    mymapView = [[MKMapView alloc]initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];

    mymapView.mapType = MKMapTypeStandard;

    mymapView.showsUserLocation = YES;

    [self.view addSubview:mymapView];
}
```

Comment: Is the map view loaded from a xib? Are you instantiating a map view in loadView, or accessing the map view outlet set in interface builder?

Comment: no i am using code no IB

Comment: The above code i pasted does not contain any errors but the question is why is it in loadView why not in init

Answer (score 0):

use debbuging pointer for checking init method calls or not.I think init method does not call

but viewDidLoad always call thats why this happens.

you can also use according to you that means show map in init by simply calling init in viewDidLoad.

Comment: viewDidLoad method always gets called as when we wana do some manipulations with the views after they are loaded in the window then we use viewDidLoad. Now the init method does gets called but b4 that when i worked with labels and buttons i used to give frames to those objects in the init method and they worked fine. For the map view if i give the frame in the init method all i am left with is a blank UIView thats all nothing else and i want to know is like why is this happening